# How to Check if location exists in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: jquery, rest, folder

I'm developing an application and a part of it involves storing user submitted documents to a document library in SharePoint. Each folder in the document library is identified by the User ID. And within each folder is a list of files the user submits

Right now I'm using jquery and the SharePoint REST API to upload files and create the folders to the document library.

Naturally, if the User ID folder does not exist, I would have to create one, so my question is, how do I check to see if that folder exists?

For example, if my ID# is 111111, I would have to check the document library for a folder of 111111 and if it's not there, create a folder titled 111111.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the client object model for this:

```
try
{
    var folder = rootweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/111111");
}
catch
{
   // Create folder here
}
```

Or by REST

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/11111')
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"
```

then you can check the response for success of failure

Comment: Thanks! And one more question, how would you recommend going about creating a folder if it doesn't exist? Is it possible to do this through jquery?

Comment: JQuery per se is not capable of creating items, but you can use both rest and client object model for this, give it a google! :)

Comment: If possible can you plese add whole code using REST

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is a old post, but just adding the complete code to check if not present then create from App web to hostweb

```
try
{
    var folder = rootweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents/NewFolder");
}
catch
{
createFolder('NewFolder');
}
function CreateFolder(newFolderName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/')/folders/add(url=\'" + newFolderName + "\')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Created Folder');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //handle error... 
            alert('Failed to create folder');
        }
    });
}
```